# Ajax and PHP not updating database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This ajax code gets called, I tested it, but the database does not get updated.
I think the code is small enough not to need any further explanation. When something from the class pdb gets clicked, it saves its source to the database.

```
$(function(){
                    $('.pdb').on('click',function(){

                        var sou = $(this).attr('src');
                        var iddo = $(this).attr('id');
                        var data = 'id='+iddo+'&value='+sou+'&turno='+(bia)?true:false;
                        $.ajax({
                             data: data,
                             type: "post",
                             url: "database.php",
                             success: function(data){
                                  alert("Prova: " + data);
                             }
                        });

                    });

                });
```

database.php

```
<?php 

        mysql_connect("localhost","pierostesting","");
        mysql_select_db("my_pierostesting");


        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $value =$_POST['value'];
        $turno=$_POST['turno'];
        if(true){

            $sql="UPDATE board SET $id=$value, turno=$turno WHERE partita=0";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);
            if($result){
                echo "Nailed it";
            }
        }else{


        }

?>
```

Comment: Oh, that if(true) used to be an if() with something, I removed that condition and kept the if for now in case it'll be needed again.

Comment: the `$id` is one of the columns in your table? Did you use any debugger and confirmed the post request was sending all the correct params?

Comment: $id is the column, all columns should be there.

Comment: By adding '' to $value I managed to make it return "nailed it". Database still doesn't get updated. EDIT: Now it works after changing a value in the database, not posting this since it's a saving mistake.

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
var data = 'id='+iddo+'&value='+sou+'&turno='+bia;
```

and debug ajax calls use either console or firebug extension

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
var data = 'id='+iddo+'&value='+sou+'&turno='+(bia)?true:false;
```

with

```
data = { 'id':iddo,'value':sou,'turno':(bia)?true:false}
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to change the PHPto this:

```
$sql="UPDATE board SET $id='$value', turno=$turno WHERE partita=0";
```

Simply change $value with '$value', bloody ''. Thank you all guys.